# Apply changes from directly downloaded repository to the remote

Tags: git, github, gitlab

[image]I directly downloaded a repository and changed a lot of code after that I initialised a new repo and connected it to the remote repository where I initially downloaded it from, now I've created a new branch then pushed my code.

What happened is that there's merging conflict, now my branch commit looks like that I've added all the code as a new code with no difference.

fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

How I can resolve this without manually re-applying my changes on the code.

Comment: that's because you ```changed a lot of code after that I **initialised a new repo**```

Comment: Can we assume that both repos are the same, or at least that contain the same code (and commits)? If that is the case, don't panic: you will not lose your edits, but you have some work to do cherry-picking changes. Start by backing up your changes, and identify the files that you have added/renamed/deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you're doing is:

- git clone something `git clone git@...` to let's say ~/repo/myrepo
- edit a lot of files (you do not remember which ones) inside ~/repo/myrepo
- delete .git directory `rm -rf ~/repo/myrepo/.git`
- initialize new git repo `git init` inside ~/repo/myrepo
- set remote to your old repo `git remote add origin git@...`
- stage all files and commit `git add . ; git commit -m 'some message'`
- then push `git push` => in this stage you got `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

If you haven't forget what files are changed, you can just reapply the changes. But if you really forget what files are changed, you can try:

- do a fresh clone of the repository `git clone git@...` (assuming you cloned to ~/repo/freshclone)
- copy the changed repo for backup, for example to ~/repo/editedrepobackup `cp -r ~/repo/myrepo ~/repo/editedrepobackup`
- remove .git directory in ~/repo/editedrepobackup `rm -rf  ~/repo/editedrepobackup`
- make an new worktree without checkout `git worktree add --no-checkout ~/repo/editedrepoworktree mybranch` (do it from ~/repo/freshclone)
- move .git file (not directory) from the new worktree to ~/repo/editedrepobackup `mv ~/repo/editedrepoworktree/.git ~/repo/editedrepobackup/.git`
- delete empty directory ~/repo/editedrepoworktree/ `rm ~/repo/editedrepoworktree/` (it should be empty)
- rename ~/repo/editedrepobackup directory to ~/repo/editedrepoworktree/ `mv ~/repo/editedrepobackup ~/repo/editedrepoworktree/`
- try to cd into ~/repo/editedrepoworktree/ and run `git status`

If everything works well, you should have a working repo that retain history of freshly cloned repo, but not losing your changes (it should be listed as unstaged changes in git status)

Then you can just (inside ~/repo/editedrepoworktree/):

- `git add .` (or preferably just pick files you intend to push)
- `git commit`

After that, you can always push `mybranch` to remote

- `git push origin mybranch`

Or you can merge your changes into ~/repo/freshclone

- `cd ~/repo/freshclone`
- `git merge --ff-only mybranch`